# Unable to run buildbot on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-22.04, buildbot

buildbot upgrade-master master is throwing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildbot", line 4, in <module>
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildbot/scripts/runner.py", line 762, in run
    subcommandFunction = reflect.namedObject(subconfig.subcommandFunction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 173, in namedObject
    module = namedModule('.'.join(classSplit[:-1]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 159, in namedModule
    topLevel = __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildbot/scripts/upgrade_master.py", line 24, in <module>
    from buildbot.db import connector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildbot/db/connector.py", line 32, in <module>
    from twisted.application import internet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/internet.py", line 54, in <module>
    from automat import MethodicalMachine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/automat/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._methodical import MethodicalMachine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/automat/_methodical.py", line 7, in <module>
    from inspect import getfullargspec as getArgsSpec
ImportError: cannot import name getfullargspec
```

Installed Packages: python2.7, python2.7-dev, buildbot=='0.8.12', buildbot-slave=='0.8.12', sqlalchemy=='0.7.10', sqlalchemy-migrate=='0.7.2', jinja2, python-dateutil, twisted==17.9.0

Comment: What version is ```automat```?  Because according to https://github.com/glyph/automat/commit/ff3ecd5159079d60095b1d1116117d635433c6a3,  they're now fully Python3 and you're still using python2.   Try downgrading ```automat``` .

Comment: Thank you @ewokx . Yes, i missed to check that. The installed `automat` version is `22.10.0`. Downgrading it to `0.7.0` has solved the issue.

Comment: Instead of downgrading, you should actually upgrade to python 3: using such an old version is a security risk as Python 2.7 has been End Of Life for a while: https://endoflife.date/python